# How to use Google api in YQL for Google Keyword Tool?

Tags: api, yql

Though this question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827794/google-keyword-tools-api) but its not aswered. 
So, i'd like to ask here. How can we get the results of [Googel keyword tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal) using YQL ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YQL comes from Yahoo Query Language - being that yahoo is not google, I doubt that you can use a Yahoo API to access a Google product.

However, there is an [Google AdWords API](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/) that you can use for this (from google) but it will cost you.

The rate is $0.25/1k calls and each getKeywordVariations (includes Search volume) = 20 calls = 0.005 each time that occurs.... and that could really add up

Comment: Well, that's cheap enough. But i'd like to use the API that we use in Google API Search. Can we access the Google Keyword tool using VB6 or Yahoo Pipes??

Comment: `The AdWords API SOAP interface is supported by all popular programming languages, including Java, PHP, Python, .NET, Perl, and Ruby` so, if you can make SOAP calls from VB6 then you are ready to go

Comment: Do i need to signup to use "AdWords API SOAP interface" ?

Comment: how will you pay if you don't?

Comment: @Tudor, lol...i thought this one is free where as the other one which you mentioned before is 25 cents! Seems like both are same :(

Comment: Google is the one who taxes for the use of its API - there is no way to have a free alternative (at least not in the business models I can think of)